# construct class by string and calling method in class by string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So i have this class: (Math.js)

```
export default class SomeMath {
    construct(value)
    {
        this.options = value

    }

    DoSomeMath(val) {
        return this.options + val;
    }
}
```

And I want to call it anonymously, And I can achieve that by doing this:

```
import * as ClassesArray from './math.js'

let ClassInString = 'SomeMath';
let MethodInString = 'DoSomeMath';

let TheClass = new ClassesArray.default[ClassInString].default(50), // Hacky way because of babel
    TheMethod = TheClass[MethodInString];

  TheMethod.call(this, 50); // Wont work.
```

The problem is, `this.options` returns empty in `DoSomeMath`. Is there a way to make this work? or is this a limitation of es6?

Comment: It seems you have your `exports` / `imports` wrong. If you correctly use `import` / `export` then you could simply do `new ClassesArray[ClassInString](50)`. *"The problem is, `this.options` returns empty in DoSomeMath"* Well, of course. You are explicitly setting `this` inside `DoSomeMath` to whatever `this` in the module refers to (`TheMethod.call(this, 50);`), not to `TheClass`. If you would call the method as a method (`TheClass[MethodInString]()`) it would work. I have the feeling you are trying to use classes for something that doesn't require classes.

Comment: ``TheMethod.call(this, 50);`` Well, quite tired and missed this... darn... However, how am I using the import / exports wrong? The code shown above is the way you do it, I assumed babel did some funky stuff to mess stuff up. And this is just an example use case for something bigger, I'm sure I require classes :)

Comment: *"I assumed babel did some funky stuff to mess stuff up"* Nope. You seem to import default exports incorrectly, or at least inconveniently. It seems, `./math.js` shoud look like `export {default as SomeMath} from './Math.js';`, then my suggestion should work.

Comment: Shouldn't `construct` be `constructor`?

Comment: @FelixKling right, thank you!